# GwtQuery droppable compile Error with GWT 2.6.1

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt, gwtquery

When compiling [GwtQuery droppable plugin](https://github.com/jDramaix/droppable) I get the following error:

```
|    Validating units:
|       [ERROR] Errors in 'gwtquery/plugins/droppable/client/gwt/DragAndDropCellBrowser.java'
|          [ERROR] Line 65: The type BrowserCellList is not visible
|          [ERROR] Line 171: The type CellBrowser.BrowserCellList<T> is not visible
|          [ERROR] Line 180: The type CellBrowser.BrowserCellList<T> is not visible
|          [ERROR] Line 197: The type CellBrowser.BrowserCellList<T> is not visible
|          [ERROR] Line 219: The method getDefaultResources() from the type CellBrowser is not visible
|          [ERROR] Line 332: The type BrowserCellList is not visible
|          [ERROR] Line 332: The method createDisplay(TreeViewModel.NodeInfo<C>, int) of type DragAndDropCellBrowser must override or implement a supertype method
|          [ERROR] Line 336: The method getLoadingIndicator() is undefined for the type DragAndDropCellBrowser
|          [ERROR] Line 337: The method getLoadingIndicator() is undefined for the type DragAndDropCellBrowser
|          [ERROR] Line 339: The method getPageSize() is undefined for the type DragAndDropCellBrowser
|          [ERROR] Line 340: The method getPageSize() is undefined for the type DragAndDropCellBrowser
|       [ERROR] Errors in 'gwtquery/plugins/droppable/client/gwt/DragAndDropCellTree.java'
|          [ERROR] Line 43: The type com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellTreeNodeView is not visible
|          [ERROR] Line 87: CellTreeNodeView cannot be resolved to a type
|          [ERROR] Line 87: The method createTreeNodeView(T, CellTree.CellTreeMessages) of type DragAndDropCellTree must override or implement a supertype method
|          [ERROR] Line 88: The constructor DragAndDropCellTreeNodeView<T>(DragAndDropCellTree, CellTreeNodeView<?>, TreeViewModel.NodeInfo<T>, Element, T, CellTree.CellTreeMessages) refers to the missing type CellTreeNodeView
|       [ERROR] Errors in 'gwtquery/plugins/droppable/client/gwt/DragAndDropCellTreeNodeView.java'
|          [ERROR] Line 25: The type com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellTreeNodeView is not visible
|          [ERROR] Line 35: CellTreeNodeView cannot be resolved to a type
|          [ERROR] Line 46: NodeCellList cannot be resolved to a type
|          [ERROR] Line 51: NodeCellList cannot be resolved to a type
|          [ERROR] Line 62: The method replaceAllChildren(List<C>, SelectionModel<? super C>, boolean) of type DragAndDropCellTreeNodeView<T>.DragAndDropNodeCellList<C>.View must override or implement a supertype method
|          [ERROR] Line 67: The method replaceAllChildren(List<C>, SelectionModel<capture#1-of ? super C>, boolean) is undefined for the type Object
|          [ERROR] Line 74: The method replaceChildren(List<C>, int, SelectionModel<? super C>, boolean) of type DragAndDropCellTreeNodeView<T>.DragAndDropNodeCellList<C>.View must override or implement a supertype method
|          [ERROR] Line 83: The method replaceChildren(List<C>, int, SelectionModel<capture#2-of ? super C>, boolean) is undefined for the type Object
|          [ERROR] Line 98: The method getNodeInfo() is undefined for the type DragAndDropCellTreeNodeView.DragAndDropNodeCellList<C>.View
|          [ERROR] Line 101: The method getNodeInfo() is undefined for the type DragAndDropCellTreeNodeView.DragAndDropNodeCellList<C>.View
|          [ERROR] Line 109: The method getNodeView() is undefined for the type DragAndDropCellTreeNodeView.DragAndDropNodeCellList<C>.View
|          [ERROR] Line 138: CellTreeNodeView cannot be resolved to a type
|          [ERROR] Line 147: NodeCellList<C> cannot be resolved to a type
|          [ERROR] Line 152: NodeCellList cannot be resolved to a type
|          [ERROR] Line 154: The method getNodeView() is undefined for the type DragAndDropCellTreeNodeView.DragAndDropNodeCellList<C>
|          [ERROR] Line 179: CellTreeNodeView cannot be resolved to a type
|          [ERROR] Line 186: CellTreeNodeView cannot be resolved to a type
|          [ERROR] Line 188: The constructor DragAndDropCellTreeNodeView<C>(DragAndDropCellTree, CellTreeNodeView<?>, TreeViewModel.NodeInfo<C>, Element, C, CellTree.CellTreeMessages) refers to the missing type CellTreeNodeView
|          [ERROR] Line 197: NodeCellList cannot be resolved to a type
|          [ERROR] Line 197: The method createNodeCellList(TreeViewModel.NodeInfo<C>) of type DragAndDropCellTreeNodeView<T> must override or implement a supertype method
|          [ERROR] Line 199: The constructor DragAndDropCellTreeNodeView.DragAndDropNodeCellList<C>(TreeViewModel.NodeInfo<C>, CellTreeNodeView<?>, int) refers to the missing type CellTreeNodeView
|    [ERROR] Aborting compile due to errors in some input files
| ================================================================
|    Compilation finished at Wed Jun 18 22:12:03 CEST 2014
| ================================================================
```

**How can I resolve this problem?**

Answer (score 1):

This usually means your GWT items are higher up on the classpath than the gwtquery + plugins.

gwtquery droppable copy/pastes some package protected classes and exposes them so you need to have those classes higher up on the classpath so they are read first.

With maven this should mean putting gwtquery stuff before your gwt stuff.

Source: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gwtquery/BKGDpJRfs_w/YhGAcTX_3T8J